# Elasticsearch connection errors at the second login

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Running elasticsearch locally. Using elasticsearch-8.3.2 and kibana-8.3.2. I'm able to run everything smoothly the first time. After some timeout, when i'm not running anything, Kibana is logging out and I can't login again.

After shutting down both services and trying to run them again, i'm getting the following error from kibana:

`[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. Request timed out`

from elasticsearch I get the following logs:

```
[2022-07-18T10:45:13,801][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] recovered [15] indices into cluster_state
[2022-07-18T10:45:13,952][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] exception during geoip databases update
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:134) ~[ingest-geoip-8.3.2.jar:8.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:274) [ingest-geoip-8.3.2.jar:8.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102) [ingest-geoip-8.3.2.jar:8.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48) [ingest-geoip-8.3.2.jar:8.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42) [elasticsearch-8.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:769) [elasticsearch-8.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) [elasticsearch-8.3.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
[2022-07-18T10:45:20,771][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]
[2022-07-18T10:45:22,147][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]
[2022-07-18T10:45:22,873][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] current.health="YELLOW" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana-event-log-8.3.2-000001][0], [.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.07.17-000001][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.kibana-event-log-8.3.2-000001][0], [.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.07.17-000001][0]]"
[2022-07-18T10:45:24,106][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]
```

trying to resolve the "exception during geoip databases update" error with adding the following line in the elasticsearch.yml file:
`ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false`

the logs in elasticsearch changed but the error in kibana stayed the same. the new logs:

```
[2022-07-18T11:44:24,317][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] recovered [15] indices into cluster_state
[2022-07-18T11:44:24,479][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetadataDeleteIndexService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] [.geoip_databases/NjfOut3sQ6u_8VPvVDeeAA] deleting index
[2022-07-18T11:44:28,744][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [tamirs-MacBook-Pro.local] current.health="YELLOW" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana-event-log-8.3.2-000001][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.kibana-event-log-8.3.2-000001][0]]"
```

I tried to generate new passwords for kibana and elasticsearch with the following commands:

```
 - bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system --auto
 - bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

but i'm getting the error:
`ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster.`
not sure if it's related.

only when i downloading or extracting the same folders again i'm able to start with a new password and credentials.

can someone help me keep my session running, or at least been able to login again after shutting out?
thanks